# Hadoop's WordCount runs form command line but not from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

In the last few days, I have tested multiple version of Hadoop (1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.1.4).  In each case, I can easily run the WordCount program using the following command line:

```
hadoop  jar  hadoop-examples-1.1.1.jar  wordcount  /input   output
```

Since the above command executes successfuly, then I assume that my Hadoop configuration is correct.  But I get the following error message for each single version when I try to run the program using exact same input from Eclipse.  **Can anyone give me the reason why it wouldn't run from Eclipse?**

```
Dec 12, 2012 2:19:41 PM org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader <clinit>
WARNING: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Dec 12, 2012 2:19:41 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient copyAndConfigureFiles
WARNING: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
****file:/tmp/wordcount/in
Dec 12, 2012 2:19:42 PM org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2 run
INFO: Cleaning up the staging area file:/tmp/hadoop-root/mapred/staging/root-41981592/.staging/job_local_0001
Dec 12, 2012 2:19:42 PM org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation doAs
SEVERE: PriviledgedActionException as:root cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/input
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/input
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:962)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:979)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$600(JobClient.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:850)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:850)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:500)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:530)
    at com.igalia.wordcount.WordCount.run(WordCount.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at com.igalia.wordcount.App.main(App.java:28)
```

Comment: `/input` usually maps to the root of the filesystem. It is very unlikely that it really exists. Can you verify that there is this folder? E.G. by `ls -l /input/*`

Comment: Also check that you have configured HDFS in your eclipse `App` correct, so it finds the `hdfs:/input` and not the `file:/input`.

Comment: I've checked that /input exists.  Also, I've tried all types of paths, and just to make sure I have the correct path, I go to the HDFS page (http://localhost:50070/dfshealth.jsp) and copy the path from there.  However, you mentioned "configured HDFS in your eclipse App correct;"  how do I do this?  I'm running just the standard WordCount that comes with Hadoop download.

Comment: Hi Thomas,  I just checked and you are quite correct, the program is looking for file:/input and not for /input.  Please do me a favor and tell me how I can get rid off that file: part.  This is driving me crazy and you are the very first person who have been able to recognize this problem.  I just assumed file: is part of the error message rather than part of the path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following two lines in your job through your Configuration abject :

```
Configuration.addResource(new Path("path-to-your-core-site.xml file"));
Configuration.addResource(new Path("path-to-your-hdfs-site.xml file"));
```

Comment: Thank you Tariq. Worked perfectly.

Comment: great. we need to tell the job where to go for namenode and datanodes.

Comment: Great..:) Worked well for me

Answer (score 0):

For hadoop-2.2.0 on windows 7, I added the below lines and it solved the issue (NOTE: My Hadoop Home is: C:\MyWork\MyProjects\Hadoop\hadoop-2.2.0)

Configuration conf = new Configuration();

conf.addResource(new Path("C:\MyWork\MyProjects\Hadoop\hadoop-2.2.0\etc\hadoop\core-site.xml"));

conf.addResource(new Path("C:\MyWork\MyProjects\Hadoop\hadoop-2.2.0\etc\hadoop\hdfs-site.xml"));